What's the significance of the number ~158.9942 in this scenario?
I was trying to create texture coordinates for a cubemap and in order to get the right masking factor for each of the faces I needed to use the geometry's normal. Dividing the absolute value of the normal by the sum of its components gets me close, but the result is basically rotated 45 degrees from what I'm expecting. I tried a lot of ways to rotate it and settled on exponentiating it until it was close enough.


The weird thing is that, at the corners of the result, the value 158.9942 gives a near-perfect point, where any value above or below 158.9942 seems to "clip" off the corner


...so what's up with this number? I was thinking maybe the decimal is related to sqrt(2) = 1.414 but I can't zoom in any further to verify if 158.99414 is any closer. But that also doesn't explain the 158.99, so is there something I'm missing?
